# For how many values of $x$ in $0 \le x < 2\pi$ does $\frac{\sin(5x)}{\sin(x)} - \frac{\cos(5x)}{\cos(x)}=2$?

Tags: trigonometry, contest-math

> For how many values of $x$ in $0 \le x < 2\pi$ does $\frac{\sin(5x)}{\sin(x)} - \frac{\cos(5x)}{\cos(x)}=2$?

Using the sine and cosine addition rules, I tried to express $\sin(5x)$ and $\cos(5x)$ in terms of $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$. However, it took me quite a while, 
and I was wondering if there was a quicker way...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint.

The equation is equivalent to

$$\frac{\sin 5x\cos x -\cos 5x\sin x}{\sin x\ \cos x} = 2$$

which is same as

$$\frac{\sin4x}{\sin 2x} = 1,$$

which in turn is same as

$$2\cos 2x = 1$$

Comment: please write the note $\sin(4x)=\sin(5x-x)=\sin(5x)\cos(-x)+\cos(5x)\sin(-x)$ and beaus of $\cos(-x)=\cos(x)$ and $\sin(-x)=-\sin(x)$ we obtain the result. In my idea, the hint is for comment and not an answer.

Comment: So would the answer be $4$?

Comment: @Helena, yep! That seems correct.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\frac{\sin\left(5x\right)}{\sin\left(x\right)}-\frac{\cos\left(5x\right)}{\cos\left(x\right)}=2 \Leftrightarrow \frac{\sin\left(5x\right)\cos(x)-\cos(5x)\sin(x)}{\sin\left(x\right)\cos(x)}=2
$$
Then you can use 
$$
\sin\left(5x\right)\cos(x)-\cos(5x)\sin(x)=\sin((5-1)x) \ \text{ and } \ 2\sin(x)\cos(x)=\sin(2x)
$$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is: using a common denominator, you get
$$\sin 5x\cos x-\sin x\cos 5x=2\sin x\cos x\iff \sin 4x=\sin 2x$$
provided $\sin x, \cos x\ne 0$. Now the *general* solutions of the last equation are given by
$$\begin{cases}
4x\equiv 2x\mod 2\pi\iff  2x\equiv 0\mod 2\pi\iff x\equiv 0\mod \pi,\\
4x\equiv \pi -2x\mod 2\pi\iff  6x\equiv \pi\mod 2\pi\iff x\equiv \dfrac\pi6\mod \dfrac\pi3.
\end{cases}$$
There remains to glean the solutions which satisfy the required conditions.

Answer (score 0):

$$sin(5x)cos(x)-cos(5x)sin(x)=2tan(x)$$
$$sin(4x)=2tan(x)$$
$$2sin(2x)cos(2x)=2tan(x)$$
can be continued from here

Comment: Use \sin(x), \cos(x) etc. for trig formatting, tends to come out better, like $\sin(x)$ as opposed to $sin(x)$